# Can I secure a webpage with something other than username/password

Tags: apache2, security, authentication

I want to secure a webpage, but I want something better than username and password. Is there any public key style authentication for a webpage? I'm not concerned with the usability / convenience of a solution.

For clarity, I'm not talking about ssl. I want the page contents blocked from someone without the "key".

Comment: maybe is additional .htaccess solution for you [here is a link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml). You can filter access to specific directory/files ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know to program, you can secure a web page with whatever you like. Whether it makes sense it is up to you. Basically, prompt the user on first access to supply whatever you want: a password, a file with a public key, a photo of his mother, a valid credit card number, and so on, and verify it using code afterwards.